# How to know I am in backstage view of MS Word using c#

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, office-addins

I am working on MS Word application. When we click in file tab in word , it opens backstage view. How do I know programmatically in C# if I am in backstage view or not. I tried checking with if ActiveWindow or ActiveDocument is null or not. But they are not working . I don't want to create/customize the ribbon xml for checking this. Is there any property in window/document/application by which I can get to know I am in backstage view of word or not.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: No, there isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Backstage UI provides the following two callbacks (events) that allow to be aware when the UI is shown and closed:

- `onHide`

```
VBA: Sub OnHide(contextObject As Object)
C#: void OnHide(object contextObject)
Visual Basic: Sub OnHide(contextObject As Object)
C++: HRESULT OnHide([in] Object *pContextObject)
```

- `onShow`

```
VBA: Sub OnShow(contextObject As Object)
C#: void OnShow(object contextObject)
Visual Basic: Sub OnShow(contextObject As Object)
C++: HRESULT OnShow([in] Object *pContextObject)
```

Read more about that in the [Introduction to the Office 2010 Backstage View for Developers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/ee691833(v=office.14)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) article.

Comment: I don't want to use or create custom backstage UI. Are there any properties in application or document by which I can get to know directly instead of implementing those callbacks

Comment: Some ribbon controls are getting inactivated (disabled). So, you can check the built-in controls state to know whether a backstage UI is visible or not.